# Beginner Algorithms/nested if statements Python 3.3

Tags: python

Okay, so I've got another question about a tic tac toe game I'm building. :P  What I'm working on is coding an A.I. that is unbeatable, so what I've right now is that if the computer starts first it will follow the necessary steps to either win or draw, however, I don't know how to use algorithms, mainly minimax(), (since this is my first actual program that I'm making) and am not too entirely sure how to simplify all my if - statements.

The code I have for the A.I. so far is as follows:

```
 if strategy == False:
    slot[0] = computer_team
    if slot[1] == user_team or slot [2] == user_team and (slot[3] != user_team) \
       and (slot[3] != computer_team):
        slot[3] = computer_team
        if slot[6] == user_team and (slot[4] != user_team) and (slot[4] != computer_team):
            slot[4] = computer_team
        else:
            return
    if slot[3] == user_team or slot[4] == user_team or slot[6] == user_team \
           and (slot[1] != user_team) and (slot[1] != computer_team):
        slot[1] = computer_team
        if slot[2] == user_team and (slot[4] != user_team) and (slot[4] != computer_team):
            slot[4] = computer_team
        elif slot[2] == user_team and slot[4] == user_team and (slot[6] != user_team) \
            and (slot[6] != computer_team):
            slot[6] = computer_team
            if slot[4] == user_team and (slot[5] != user_team) and (slot[5] != computer_team):
                slot[5] = computer_team
            elif slot[7] == user_team and slot[5] == computer_team and (slot[8] != user_team) and (slot[8] != computer_team):
                    slot[8] = computer_team
        else:
            return
    else:
        return
```

One thing that I've found to be an issue is that once the if statements get nested in so far they stop executing (in this case, the last elif slot[7]).  I know that this code is inefficient, but it's the only way I know how to do it. (I'm not sure how I'd use for statements or range here). So if any of you have suggestions on algorithms or how to simplify this if nest mess, then I'd be happy to hear. c:

Edit: All the slot mess refers to my board, which is:

```
def draw_board():
'''Opted to use lists so that the numbers can be replaced with either
    X or O later on and so that testing whether the game is over is simpler'''
print (" " + str(slot[0]) + " | " + str(slot[1]) + " | " + str(slot[2]))
print ("-----------")
print (" " + str(slot[3]) + " | " + str(slot[4]) + " | " + str(slot[5]))
print ("-----------")
print (" " + str(slot[6]) + " | " + str(slot[7]) + " | " + str(slot[8]))
print ("\n")
```

And user_team/computer_team holds either "X" or "O", depending on which one the player chooses to use.

Comment: can you provide a pastebin (http://pastebin.com/) of your code?  I want to run it myself and see exactly what's going on (easier to debug in the trenches than from the bridge of a ship at sea =P)

Comment: @JustinCarroll http://pastebin.com/9VbzpgWe  To see the issue with the if-statement not executing, restart till the computer starts first, and then for your moves, do 4, 2, 3, 7. :P

Comment: thanks - looking at it now.  What version of python are you using?  3+? 2.7?

Comment: @JustinCarroll Ahhh, forgot to put that in the title this time. ;O I'm on 3.3

Comment: I'm running 2.7 myself, made some minor changes for backwards compatibility (namely converting `input` to `raw_input`), but I'm not seeing any problems with the pattern 4, 2, 3, 7 -- aka the code completed, and it said "The game is a tie" and prompted me to another infuriating game =P.  Are you getting an explicit error/traceback that you can post?  Or is just hanging?

Comment: Whattt? When I run it, the computer just doesn't choose 8 and the turn is passed back to me. (Either the elif doesn't execute, or it's getting stuck somewhere. ;O) I mean, the game STILL results in a tie, but I'm using this for an apprenticeship application, so it'd be sweet if it all ran. xD

Comment: ah I see what you are getting (I get that too, I was expecting to see a traceback when I ran and glazed over that).  Looking at it now.  Give me a min.

Comment: btw, don't forget to add the "green check" to show that your question was answered - this helps others know that they don't need to spend time reading a solved question (and shows whomever answered your question/solved your problem that it they indeed found the problem).

Comment: Ah, forgot all about that. Thanks! And you got your green check. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few other 'bugs', but to answer your question...

It looks like your problem is here:

```
elif slot[2] == user_team and slot[4] == user_team and (slot[6] != user_team) \
and (slot[6] != computer_team):
```

by the time you follow the pattern you provided `4, 2, 3, 7` the board looks like:

```
 O | O | X
-----------
 X | X | O
-----------
 O | X | 8
```

Which the above condition does not satisfy.  For instance, what you wrote reads:

```
if Slot2 = User, Slot4 = User, Slot6 != User, and Slot6 != Computer either...
```

And the board reads:

```
Slot2 = User, Slot4 = User, Slot6 != User, and Slot6 = Computer
```

I just removed `and (slot[6] != computer_team)` from what is line 192 for me, and it seems to work just fine now.

Let me know if this fixed your first (of what may be many) problems (there are a few other points of errata throughout, but if you work your way through it you'll find 'em all in good time).

This is solid - good job.

Comment: Yep, that definitely did it! All those if/elif statements can become quite a lot. >.< But well, now I know how to solve that error if it pops up in another scenario!

And well, I'm not surprised that there are other errors, but I'll probably run into them at one point. xD Thanks for the help, and your time! I'm now back to grinding out all of the possible  moves for the ai. :P

Comment: I recommend the use of a poor-mans debugger by way of `print()`.  I found this bug by looking at your nesting, and then adding `print` to various places to see what places were actually firing.  Then when I saw some places lit-up and others stayed dark, I knew where to focus.  Or... you could just use a debugger like the pros and step through it haha.

Comment: Hmm, print to debug? That's actually a good idea. I'll use that in the future, and maybe I'll use the debugger. I'll have to throw out some intentional errors and missed loops in a test just to get a feel for it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at

http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaGame_TicTacToe_AI.html

It takes you step by step on building solutions for tic tac toe. Note, it starts by introducing a table-based implementation similar to what you have done here and proceeds to start using tree-based solutions.

Comment: I'll go take a look and see if I can find something that'll help. :)